# template instantiation with multiple template inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

What are the rules for template instantiation when we pass a (multi)derived class to a template function expecting base class? For example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int x>
struct C {};

struct D : C<0>, C<1> {};

template <int x>
void f (const C<x> &y)  { std::cout << x << "\n"; }

int main ()
{
  f (D ());
}
```

MSVC 2015 prints 0, clang 3.8 - 1 and gcc 6.2 gives compiler error ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d75ce35959e63ea8)). And even if you SFINAE-away all overloads except one, the result will still be different:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int x> struct C {};

template<>
struct C<0> { using type = void; };

struct D : C<0>, C<1> {};

template <int x, typename = typename C<x>::type>
void f (const C<x> &y)  { std::cout << x << "\n"; }

int main ()
{
  f (D ());
}
```

Now it compiles only with MSVC, and if you swap `C<0>` and `C<1>` only clang will compile it. The problem is that MSVC only tries to instantiate first base, clang - last and gcc prints error too early. Which compiler is right?

Comment: seems to me as if they're all wrong. Shouldn't it be an ambiguous function call?

Comment: *"MSVC prints 0, clang - 1 and gcc gives compiler error."*, which MSVC, which gcc and which clang?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Added version numbers, but they all behave the same

Comment: clang 4.0 rejects both examples (although 3.8 compiles them)

Comment: C++ never gives any preference to the first (or the last or any other) base, so any compiler that arbitrarily picks a base is wrong. Reordering bases should have no effect on program validity (maybe there are some corner cases when there is not true but this is definitely not one of them; I cannot think up any off the top of my head).

Answer (score 1):

gcc 5.4:

```
/tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler11685-58-1h67lnf/example.cpp: In function 'int main()':
13 : error: no matching function for call to 'f(D)'
f (D ());
^
9 : note: candidate: template<int x> void f(const C<x>&)
void f (const C<x> &y) { std::cout << x << "\n"; }
^
9 : note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
13 : note: 'const C<x>' is an ambiguous base class of 'D'
f (D ());
^
Compilation failed
```

Which seems to me to be the correct result, since C<0> and C<1> are equally specialised.

Same result for gcc 6.2

clang 3.8.1 compiles it, which in my view is a compiler bug.

update:

I don't know the actual use case but I was wonder whether this might work for you:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct has_type
{
    template<class U> static auto test(U*) -> decltype(typename U::type{}, std::true_type());
    static auto test(...) -> decltype(std::false_type());
    using type = decltype(test((T*)0));
    static const auto value = type::value;
};

template <int x> struct C {};

template<>
struct C<0> { using type = int; };

template<int...xs>
struct enumerates_C : C<xs>...
{
};

struct D : enumerates_C<0, 1> {};

template<int x, std::enable_if_t<has_type<C<x>>::value>* = nullptr>
void f_impl(const C<x>& y)
{
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}

template<int x, std::enable_if_t<not has_type<C<x>>::value>* = nullptr>
void f_impl(const C<x>& y)
{
    // do nothing
}

template <int...xs>
void f (const enumerates_C<xs...> &y)
{
    using expand = int[];
    void(expand { 0,
        (f_impl(static_cast<C<xs> const &>(y)),0)...
    });
}

int main ()
{
    f (D ());
}
```

expected output (tested on apple clang):

```
0
```

Comment: In first example - yes, I think it should be ambiguous, in second - no, only overload for C<0> should be enabled.

Comment: "*only overload for C<0> should be enabled*" what makes you think the compiler should attempt to use each possible `x` ? first deduction takes place, which fails

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I'm asking this question to learn how it should be done. If you manually write this functions, then it will work as intended:
    https://gist.github.com/telishev/a52483833ae6850df69e1e6953f6b277

Comment: @AlexTelishev there is no deduction involved in this gist, only overload resolution and SFINAE. substitution failure can take place based on what was deduced; in such a case, the compiler falls back to other overload, not to other possible instantiation of the same template

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, I wanted to say that without deduction it works. Is there a way to force it for all base classes?

Comment: @AlexTelishev I think you cannot obtain the list of base classes

Comment: @AlexTelishev update added to allow enumeration of base classes - if you add some scaffolding.

Comment: @RichardHodges Using parameter pack expansion here is really cool, thanks!