# Clang vs GCC: CRTP inheritance

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, multiple-inheritance, crtp

Is it valid to use a CRTP class as a base to another class that itself is a CRTP class (of the same type)?

Clang (3.8.1) accepts the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Printable {};

template <typename T>
void print(const Printable<T>& p)
{
    static_cast<const T&>(p).print();
}

struct Foo : public Printable<Foo>
{
    void print() const { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; }
};

struct Bar : public Foo, public Printable<Bar> {};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    print(b);
}
```

GCC (6.1) does not:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'print(Bar&)' print(b);
```

Who is correct?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @n.m. Added error

Comment: [Clang 4.0](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/j1DQgBwKNW3mnfmA) fails.

Comment: It is worth noting that there is further detail in the error `const Printable<T>' is an ambiguous base class of 'Bar'`...

Comment: To me it looks ambiguous no matter what. `Bar` **is-a** `Printable<Bar>`  and `Bar` **is-a** `Printable<Foo`. The special rules for dominance (in virtual virtual inheritance) don't kick in here. So, simply dis-ambiguate by using a cast of the argument `b`. Out of curiousity, what interpretation does the accepting clang compiler use?

Comment: If two compilers that are in common use cannot agree how to compile your code, then maybe you should take that as a sign not to write code like that.

Comment: It is a bug in clang 3.x, same as e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331632/template-instantiation-with-multiple-template-inheritance).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Seems to be the 2nd base class, i.e. `Printable<Bar>`, according to the link posted by n.m.

Comment: @n.m.I would even say this question is a perfect dupe of that, isn't it?